# Meteor: Access variable across all Meteor.method's

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm pretty new to Meteor, but I just made a simple turn-based multiplayer game.

When player 2 connects I make an update on the Game collection within a `Meteor.method`. But when I, in another `Meteor.method` wants to get that update, then I need to `Games.find()` it again, to get that updated value.

How can I store the current Game instance, where I can access it with all my `Meteor.method's`?

If it was on client-side, I would use `reactive-vars` but I guess that's not an option?

**Edit:**

```
Meteor.methods({
    startGame: function() {
        return Games.insert({
            players: [{
                _id: Meteor.userId()
            }]
        });
    },
    joinGame: function(game) {
        return Games.update({
            _id: game._id
        }, {
            $set: {
                endsAt: new Date().getTime() + 10000
            },
            $push: {
                players: Meteor.userId()
            }
        });
    },
    getDataFromGame: function() {
        // How can I get data from the
        // game inside other Methods
        // without using Games.find
        // ??
    }
});
```

I tried saving the current game inside the methods object, but then it wasn't reactive. Don't know what to do next.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a game from a `Meteor.call()` just *publish* the game(s) the user has joined.

```
Meteor.publish('myGames',function(){
   return Games.find({ players: { $elemMatch: { _id: this.userId }}});
});
```

Then on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('myGames');
```

I should point out that in your code in `startGame` the `players` key contains an array of objects `{_id: Meteor.userId()}` whereas in `startGame` the same key just contains an array of user `_id`s. Pick one and go with it. The array form is simpler here in which case your publish function will be:

```
Meteor.publish('myGames',function(){
   return Games.find({ players: this.userId });
});
```